# AccessViolationException at Runtime

Tags: c#, runtime-error, runtime.exec

I get this run time error

> 'System.AccessViolationException' inner exception ==>"Attempted to
>   read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other
>   memory is corrupt.

and here is my code

```
 private AutoCompleteStringCollection GetLinqDataSourceForString(string p)
{
    var c = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    c.Add( Getauto(p));
    return c;
}


   private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
      txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = GetLinqDataSourceForString(txtSearch.Text);
}
```

and this one is in another layer to get info from data Base

```
 public string AutoUpdate(string _search)
{
    using (var context = new Phone_BookEntities1())
    {
        var c = (from d in context.Cantacts
                 where d.Cantact1.StartsWith(_search)
                 select d.Cantact1).SingleOrDefault();
        return c;
    }
}
```

and here is where run time error occurred (in the last line)

```
  static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

and also i used this method on it in order to enter only text(string)

```
    private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9')
            e.Handled = false;
        else
            e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: The call stack would be useful in debugging the root cause of this issue; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901530/c-sharp-error-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-or-external-compone for more help.

Comment: @dash Thanks for you're help

Answer (score 0):

You should set you Debugger in VS2005:

Tools->Options

Debugging->General

uncheck option "Suppress JIT optimization on module load"